# Need help fixing the output of my project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

```
int department;
Button search;
String display;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    department = 0;
    search = (Button) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("btnSearch", "id",    getPackageName()));
    display = (String) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("tvDisplay", "id",      getPackageName()));

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (department == 1)
            {
                display = "food";
            }
```

What i'm trying to do is to have a user put in a number, hit a button, and it will display a department name at the textView i have at the bottom.  However, i've gotten errors and i've converted several parts of it to string instead of textView.  How do i fix where the output goes?

`display = (String) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("tvDisplay", "id",      getPackageName()));` is saying it can't convert from View to String.

Comment: are you want `display as a string or textView`

Comment: Please show us main.xml file and also paste complete code, this code have missing braces

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
TextView display = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("tvDisplay", "id", getPackageName()));

// get the text
String displayString = (String)display.getText();
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are converting a textview to a string. You should change type of `display` to `TextView`, and use its `setText` method to display text in it, try following code:

```
int department;
Button search;
TextView display;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    department = 0;
    search = (Button) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("btnSearch", "id", getPackageName()));
    display = (TextView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("tvDisplay", "id", getPackageName()));

    search.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (department == 1)
            {
                display.setText("food");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

tvDisplay is a TextView, not a String. So make display a TextView, find the view, and then call display.getText() to get the displayed text.